# Invalid parameter: JSON must contain an entry for 'default' or 'APNS_SANDBOX'. => APNS Error in Scala (lift framework)

Tags: json, scala, notifications, apple-push-notifications, lift

I'm getting APN Invalid parameter: JSON must contain an entry for 'default' or 'APNS_SANDBOX'. the log is here

[image]

And the code block is here:

[image]

how to fix this? this is built in scala lift framework.

Answer (score 2):

This is the example in javascript.  In the same way, we have to use. Need to use cases for
1.APNS_SANDBOX
2.APNS
3.default

```
  // Setup SNS Client
const snsClient = new SNS();
// whatever your full endpoint arn is. (from createPlatformEndpoint)
const endpointArn = 'arn:aws:sns:...';
// any extra data you want passed along with the message
const payload = {
  someCustomKey: 'someCustomValue'
};
// send it
snsClient.publish({
  TargetArn: endpointArn,
  MessageStructure: 'json', // so we can put in a custom payload and message
  Message: JSON.stringify({
    default: `DEFAULT MESSAGE ${message}`,
    APNS_SANDBOX: JSON.stringify({
      aps: {
        alert: `IOS Sandbox SPECIFIC MESSAGE ${message}`,
      },
      payload,
    }),
    APNS: JSON.stringify({
      aps: {
        alert: `IOS Prod SPECIFIC MESSAGE ${message}`,
      },
      payload,
    }),
  }),
  }).promise().then(() => {
   console.log('Notification sent!');
  }).catch((err) => {
   console.log('Failed to send with:', err);
  });
```

[Used this link for reference](https://medium.com/@duhseekoh/send-a-push-notification-using-aws-sns-javascript-sdk-2f117e9c4180)